# I want to make a dynamic display and hide button and i have ejs template

Tags: javascript, html, mongoose, ejs

This is my schema and controller js:

```
const foodSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  foodName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "A food must have a name"],
  },
  Link: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "A food must have a link"],
    unique: true,
  },
  emoji: {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

```
const Food = require("../models/foodModel");
Food.find({}, function (err, foundItems) {
    res.status(200).render("icook", {
      foodName: foundItems,
    });
  });
```

icook.ejs

```
<div class="meat-table" >
  <% for(let i=0; i<foodName.length; i++) { %>
     <button class="meat-butn-on" id="click">
       <%- foodName[i].emoji %> <%= foodName[i].foodName %>  
     </button>
  <% } %>
</div>
<div class="result">
 Let&apos;s see what&apos;s delicacy for today!
   <% for(let i=0; i<foodName.length; i++) { %>
     <p class="testing"  id="try"><a href="<%= foodName[i].Link %>" role="button"><%= foodName[i].foodName %></a></p>
   <% } %>
</div>
```

My display.js

```
let b = 1;
var Test = document.getElementsByClassName("meat-butn-on");
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("testing");

for (let i = 0; i < Test.length; i++) {
  Test[i].onclick = function () {
    b++;
    if (b % 2 == 0) {
      btn.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      btn.style.display = "none";
    }
  };
}
```

everything works perfect except this `display.js`, when i click any button from class `meat-butn-on`, the console shows the error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')` why is that? I tried use class name from div class but it didn't work either. appreciate any helps

Comment: @DreamBold that didn't work  so.. but thank you !

Comment: is the same error ```Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')
    at Test.<computed>.onclick```, it points to this line ``` btn.style.display = "block"; ```

Comment: i saw this ```div {
    display: block;
} user agent stylesheet ``` when i hover over result div class

Comment: You'd better try to use naming convention of your variables, like `meatButtons` or something like that :):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working code. `querySelectorAll` returns an iterable array of elements, so you'd better use it.

```js
let b = 1;

var meatButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".meat-butn-on");
var foodNames= document.querySelectorAll(".testing");
console.log(meatButtons, foodNames);

meatButtons.forEach((t, i) => {
  t.addEventListener("click", function () {
    b++;
    if (b % 2 == 0) {
      foodNames[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      foodNames[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="meat-table">

  <button class="meat-butn-on">
    Food Name1
  </button>
  <button class="meat-butn-on">
    Food Name2
  </button>
  <button class="meat-butn-on">
    Food Name3
  </button>

</div>
<div class="result">
  Let&apos;s see what&apos;s delicacy for today!

  <p class="testing"><a href="#" role="button">Food Name1</a></p>
  <p class="testing"><a href="#" role="button">Food Name2</a></p>
  <p class="testing"><a href="#" role="button">Food Name3</a></p>

</div>
```

Live demo here: https://codepen.io/dreambold/pen/dyKBJXK?editors=1111

PS: You have an issue assigning the same `id` for the buttons, `id="click"`. You should remove this from the buttons, as `id`'s should be unique in a document. The same error is happening in the next paragraph for `p` tags.

So the code for the buttons will look like this:

```
<button class="meat-butn-on">
   <%- foodName[i].emoji %> <%= foodName[i].foodName %>  
</button>
```

Comment: OMG, i was testing it on my side, it didnt show any errors but display and hide function wasnt working, but latest one you edited was working!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you so much !!!!!!!!